# Monitor visited URLs in Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make a Chrome extension as privacy-friendly as possible.

I'm getting the permissions message that the extension can read and change all data on any website.  I actually don't need to be able to read or change any content on any website.

Here's my background script:

```
chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener((details) => {
    if(details.type == "main_frame"){
        newext(details.url);
    }
},{urls: ["http://*/*","https://*/*"]},["responseHeaders"]);

function newext(url){
    /// CODE THAT USES THE URL
}
```

Here's my `manifest.json` file:

```
{
    "name": "NewExt",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "background": { "scripts": ["background.js"]},
    "permissions": ["webRequest", "activeTab", "http://*/*", "https://*/*", "storage", "unlimitedStorage"]
}
```

I'm guessing this is what's causing that message:

```
chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener
```

Is there an alternative to `webRequest` that I can use to monitor what URLs a person visits that won't cause that permissions message to show?

Comment: This is how webRequest API works. It sees only URLs you listed in `permissions`. You can use chrome.tabs.onUpdated instead, depending on what your ultimate goal is. And naturally you'll need to remove `http://*/*", "https://*/*"` from permissions.